# Is there a standard symbol for "directionless" division?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, integers

Similar to the absolute value or modulus symbol |x|, I need a new symbol to express division of two integers regardless of order such that numerator >= denominator to produce an answer with an absolute quotient |q| > 0 and an absolute remainder |r| >= 0.

Is there a standard symbol for such directionless division, or should the math community invent a new the symbol like a 90° rotated ÷ or |÷|?

Here is a sample usage:

[image]

Comment: How can order not matter?   You really want 6/3 and 3/6 to be indistinguishable?

Comment: yes I do. Just as we can take absolute values without regards to the sign of a quantity.

Comment: Then I am dying to know how this is useful.

Comment: By "whole" integers, do you mean *positive* integers?

Comment: I should have said Z not W (positive or negative integers but no zero to avoid division by 0).

Comment: It appears that in every case in your table you are dividing the larger by the smaller.  This seems at odds with your question.  So, to clarify, what should the output of $2 \ominus 6$ be, where I have used a TeXable symbol for your unordered division?

Comment: 2 ⊖ 6 = 3 remainder 0

Comment: @AliAdams, in order for $q$ and $r$ to both be non-negative, the two numbers you start with will need to have the same sign.

Comment: Thank you, I will update the question to read: |q| > 0 and |r| >= 0.

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is not a special division but a function,

$$\langle x\rangle=\begin{cases}|x|\le1\to\dfrac1x,\\|x|\ge1\to x.\end{cases}$$

In fact, it can be related to the absolute value by

$$\exp(|\log(x)|)$$ (the sign of $x$ being kept apart) and is indeed a useful operation. But I have no notation to suggest.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109977/discussion-on-answer-by-yves-daoust-is-there-a-standard-symbol-for-directionles).